# What package can I use to generate these frames and arrows

Tags: diagrams

A collaborator drafted this image in word

[image]

What are some latex packages that could generate something like this? I am most familiar with `tikz` and `mdframes`, but it would take me some time to figure out how to make these three frames with the arrows together. Anyone have a better option before I start going in deep?

Comment: TikZ would do fine. Use the `single arrow` shape from the `shapes.arrows` library for the arrows (with `draw=white,fill=someblueishcolour`), and regular rectangular nodes for the boxes.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try and report back if I run into any issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP said he would report back if there was any issue, but he didn't, so there aren't.